# RDM630 RFID Reader on Beaglebone Black?

Tags: rfid

I have an RFID reader RDM-630 with these specifications: http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/datasheet/RDM630-Spec..pdf

Could I connect this to a Beaglebone Black?

Comment: Yes.  But why ask us?

Comment: BBB I believe is off topic for the site: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for and the answer is yes.